# Protecting Sensitive Data for a NodeJS backend code using MongoDB database and a Webpack frontend code using Google Maps API

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, webpack, google-maps-api-3

I wrote a NodeJS backend code and a Webpack frontend code communicating between each other.
In the backend, I use MongoDB as a database.
And in the frontend, I use Google Maps API.

The application works fine right now.

Now, my goal is to deploy the Webpack frontend to GitHub pages and the NodeJS backend to Heroku, so that I can launch my app online.

But, before that, I would like to protect my sensitive data with two `.env` files: one for the backend where I will store my MongoDB credentials and another one for the frontend where I will store my Google Maps API key.

The problem is I am struggling accessing the environment variables in my backend and frontend codes.

I tried many solutions and I ended up with my app behaving weirdly or getting errors like 'google is not defined'.

So, what are the steps I have to follow to protect my sensitive data without crashing my app, taking account of all the details mentioned above and my code I'm providing below:

**Backend code:**

- package.json:

```
{
  "name": "javascript-complete-guide",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "Sofiane Abou Abderrahim",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "ejs": "^2.7.1",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "mongodb": "^3.3.2"
  }
}
```

- app.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

const locationRoutes = require('./routes/location');

const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST, GET, OPTIONS');
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');
  next();
});

app.use(locationRoutes);

app.listen(3000);
```

- location.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const mongodb = require('mongodb');
const MongoClient = mongodb.MongoClient;

const router = express.Router();

const url =
  'mongodb+srv://<username>:<password>@cluster0.mztbbsh.mongodb.net/locations?retryWrites=true&w=majority';

const client = new MongoClient(url);

const locationStorage = {
  locations: []
};

router.post('/add-location', (req, res, next) => {
  client.connect(function (err, client) {
    const db = client.db('locations');

    // Insert a single document
    db.collection('user-locations').insertOne(
      {
        address: req.body.address,
        coords: { lat: req.body.lat, lng: req.body.lng }
      },
      function (err, r) {
        // if (err) {}
        console.log(r);
        res.json({ message: 'Stored location!', locId: r.insertedId });
      }
    );
  });
});

router.get('/location/:lid', (req, res, next) => {

  client.connect(function (err, client) {
    const db = client.db('locations');

    let locationId;
    try {
      locationId = new mongodb.ObjectId(req.params.lid);
    } catch (error) {
      // return to make sure the other code does not execute
      return res.status(500).json({ message: 'Invalid id!' });
    }

    db.collection('user-locations').findOne(
      {
        _id: locationId
      },
      function (err, doc) {
        if (!doc) {
          return res.status(404).json({ message: 'Not found!' });
        }
        res.json({ address: doc.address, coordinates: doc.coords });
      }
    );
  });
});

module.exports = router;
```

**Frontend code:**

- package.json:

```
{
  "name": "my-place",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "build:dev": "webpack-dev-server",
    "build": "webpack",
    "build:prod": "webpack --config webpack.config.prod.js"
  },
  "author": "Sofiane Abou Abderrahim",
  "license": "ISC",
  "browserslist": "> 0.5%",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.6.2",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.6.2",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.6",
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.0",
    "core-js": "^3.2.1",
    "regenerator-runtime": "^0.13.3",
    "webpack": "^4.40.2",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.9",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.8.1"
  }
}
```

- webpack.config.js and webpack.config.prod.js:

```
const path = require('path');
const CleanPlugin = require('clean-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  mode: 'development',
  entry: {
    'SharePlace': './src/SharePlace.js',
    'MyPlace': './src/MyPlace.js',
  },
  output: {
    filename: '[name].js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist', 'assets', 'scripts'),
    publicPath: 'assets/scripts/'
  },
  devtool: 'cheap-module-eval-source-map',
  devServer: {
    contentBase: './dist'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.m?js$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules)/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: {
            presets: [
              [
                '@babel/preset-env',
                { useBuiltIns: 'usage', corejs: { version: 3 } }
              ]
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [new CleanPlugin.CleanWebpackPlugin()]
};
```

- dist/index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>Share a Place</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/styles/app.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/styles/share-place.css" />
    <script
      src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=Function.prototype"
      defer
    ></script>
    <script src="assets/scripts/SharePlace.js" defer></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <template id="modal-template">
      <div class="backdrop"></div>
      <div class="modal"></div>
    </template>
    <template id="loading-modal-content">
      <div class="modal__content centered">
        <div class="lds-dual-ring"></div>
      </div>
    </template>

    <header>
      <h1>Share a Place!</h1>
    </header>

    <section id="selected-place">
      <div id="map">
        <p>
          You haven't selected any place yet. Please enter an address or locate
          yourself!
        </p>
      </div>
    </section>

    <section id="share-controls">
      <input
        id="share-link"
        type="text"
        readonly
        value="Select a place to get a sharable link."
      />
      <button id="share-btn" disabled>Share Place</button>
    </section>

    <section id="place-data">
      <form>
        <label for="address">Address</label>
        <input type="text" />
        <button type="submit">Find Place</button>
      </form>
      <button id="locate-btn">Get Current Location</button>
    </section>
  </body>
</html>
```

- dist/my-place/index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>My Place</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../assets/styles/app.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../assets/styles/my-place.css" />
    <script
      src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=Function.prototype"
      defer
    ></script>
    <script src="../assets/scripts/MyPlace.js" defer></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
      <h1></h1>
    </header>

    <section id="selected-place">
      <div id="map"></div>
    </section>

    <section id="share-controls">
      <a href="/">Share a New Place!</a>
    </section>
  </body>
</html>
```

- src/UI/Map.js:

```
export class Map {
  constructor(coords) {
    // this.coordinates = coords;
    this.render(coords);
  }

  render(coordinates) {
    if (!google) {
      alert('Could not load maps library - please try again later!');
      return;
    }

    const map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      center:coordinates,
      zoom: 16
    });

    new google.maps.Marker({
      position: coordinates,
      map: map
    });
  }
}
```

- src/Utility/Location.js:

```
const GOOGLE_API_KEY = 'YOUR_API_KEY';

export async function getAddressFromCoords(coords) {
  const response = await fetch(
    `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=${coords.lat},${coords.lng}&key=${GOOGLE_API_KEY}`
  );
  if (!response.ok) {
    throw new Error('Failed to fetch address. Please try again!');
  }
  const data = await response.json();
  if (data.error_message) {
    throw new Error(data.error_message);
  }
  const address = data.results[0].formatted_address;
  return address;
}

export async function getCoordsFromAddress(address) {
  const urlAddress = encodeURI(address);
  const response = await fetch(
    `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=${urlAddress}&key=${GOOGLE_API_KEY}`
  );
  if (!response.ok) {
    throw new Error('Failed to fetch coordinates. Please try again!');
  }
  const data = await response.json();
  if (data.error_message) {
    throw new Error(data.error_message);
  }

  const coordinates = data.results[0].geometry.location;
  return coordinates;
}
```

- src/MyPlace.js:

```
import { Map } from './UI/Map';

class LoadedPlace {
  constructor(coordinates, address) {
    new Map(coordinates);
    const headerTitleEl = document.querySelector('header h1');
    headerTitleEl.textContent = address;
  }
}

const url = new URL(location.href);
const queryParams = url.searchParams;

const locId = queryParams.get('location');
fetch('http://localhost:3000/location/' + locId)
  .then(response => {
    if (response.status === 404) {
      throw new Error('Could not find location!');
    }
    if (response.status === 500) {
      throw new Error('Invalid id!');
    }
    return response.json();
  })
  .then(data => {
    new LoadedPlace(data.coordinates, data.address);
  })
  .catch(err => {
    alert(err.message);
  });
```

- src/SharePlace.js:

```
import { Modal } from './UI/Modal';
import { Map } from './UI/Map';
import { getCoordsFromAddress, getAddressFromCoords } from './Utility/Location';

class PlaceFinder {
  constructor() {
    const addressForm = document.querySelector('form');
    const locateUserBtn = document.getElementById('locate-btn');
    this.shareBtn = document.getElementById('share-btn');

    locateUserBtn.addEventListener('click', this.locateUserHandler.bind(this));
    this.shareBtn.addEventListener('click', this.sharePlaceHandler);
    addressForm.addEventListener('submit', this.findAddressHandler.bind(this));
  }

  sharePlaceHandler() {
    const sharedLinkInputElement = document.getElementById('share-link');
    if (!navigator.clipboard) {
      sharedLinkInputElement.select();
      return;
    }

    navigator.clipboard
      .writeText(sharedLinkInputElement.value)
      .then(() => {
        alert('Copied into clipboard!');
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
        sharedLinkInputElement.select();
      });
  }

  selectPlace(coordinates, address) {
    if (this.map) {
      this.map.render(coordinates);
    } else {
      this.map = new Map(coordinates);
    }
    fetch('http://localhost:3000/add-location', {
      method: 'POST',
      body: JSON.stringify({
        address: address,
        lat: coordinates.lat,
        lng: coordinates.lng
      }),
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      }
    })
      .then(response => {
        return response.json();
      })
      .then(data => {
        const locationId = data.locId;
        this.shareBtn.disabled = false;
        const sharedLinkInputElement = document.getElementById('share-link');
        sharedLinkInputElement.value = `${
          location.origin
        }/my-place?location=${locationId}`;
      });
  }

  locateUserHandler() {
    if (!navigator.geolocation) {
      alert(
        'Location feature is not available in your browser - please use a more modern browser or manually enter an address.'
      );
      return;
    }
    const modal = new Modal(
      'loading-modal-content',
      'Loading location - please wait!'
    );
    modal.show();
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
      async successResult => {
        const coordinates = {
          lat: successResult.coords.latitude + Math.random() * 50,
          lng: successResult.coords.longitude + Math.random() * 50
        };
        const address = await getAddressFromCoords(coordinates);
        modal.hide();
        this.selectPlace(coordinates, address);
      },
      error => {
        modal.hide();
        alert(
          'Could not locate you unfortunately. Please enter an address manually!'
        );
      }
    );
  }

  async findAddressHandler(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    const address = event.target.querySelector('input').value;
    if (!address || address.trim().length === 0) {
      alert('Invalid address entered - please try again!');
      return;
    }
    const modal = new Modal(
      'loading-modal-content',
      'Loading location - please wait!'
    );
    modal.show();
    try {
      const coordinates = await getCoordsFromAddress(address);
      this.selectPlace(coordinates, address);
    } catch (err) {
      alert(err.message);
    }
    modal.hide();
  }
}

const placeFinder = new PlaceFinder();
```

I tried to create two .env files: one for the backend where I stored my MongoDB credentials and another one where I stored my Google Maps API key.

Then, to handle the environment variables access in the frontend and the backend, I installed some Webpack packages, like htmlwebpackplugin, dotenv, etc.

Finally, in my code, I inserted these variables.

However, I get errors like 'google is not defined'.

I think I need someone to explain me all the steps because I'm struggling right now.

Comment: For backend, you can add your variables on Heroku under your app's `Settings -> Config Vars`. Now in the code, you can access them via `process.env.VARIABLE_NAME`. Ref: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars#using-the-heroku-dashboard

Comment: @PrerakSola: Yes, for backend, it is possible to protect the sensitive data directly in Heroku. However, my problem is related to frontend and Google Maps API key.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue.
I wanted to protect my sensitive data from frontend and backend.
So, I stored it in `.env` files as variables and tried to access it in my code.

But, a quick solution was to create a `key.js` file for example, where I stored my Google Maps API key in a `key` constant.

```
export const key = 'my-api-key';
```

Then, I imported this `key` in the files that use this API key, which are:

- `MyPlace.js` and `SharePlace.js`:

```
import { key } from '../key';

document.querySelector('script').src =`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=${key}&callback=Function.prototype`;
```

- `Location.js`:

```
import { key } from '../../key';

export async function getAddressFromCoords(coords) {
    const response = await fetch(
      `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json? 
       latlng=${coords.lat},${coords.lng}&key=${key}`
    );
    ...
}

export async function getCoordsFromAddress(address) {
    const urlAddress = encodeURI(address);
    const response = await fetch(
      `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json? 
       address=${urlAddress}&key=${key}`
    );
    ...
}
```

Then, in my HTML code, I removed the **src** attribute and left `<script defer></script>`:

- `dist/index.html`:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/styles/app.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/styles/share-place.css" />
<script defer></script>
<script src="assets/scripts/SharePlace.js" defer></script>
```

- `dist/my-place/index.html`:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../assets/styles/app.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../assets/styles/my-place.css" />
<script defer></script>
<script src="../assets/scripts/MyPlace.js" defer></script>
```

For the backend, I protect my sensitive data with environment variables set up in Heroku.

Now, my sensitive data are protected.
However, it is still possible to see the frontend data when I push it online with GitHub Pages for example.
And I don't think there is a way to change this.